# onResume got error

Tags: java, android, onresume

I have a situation here. On the `StartActivity.java` onCreate method I will check whether a user turn on their GPS or not. If the GPS is off, user need to turn on and go to settings. So the `activity` will be `onPause`. When the user enter back to the apps, it will go through the `onResume`.

Then it will move to another activity called `MainActivity.java`. In this activity will generate a maps.

**StartActivity.java**

```
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_start);

        if (Utils.isGPSEnabled(this)) {
            if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
                requestPermissions(PERMISSIONS_LOCATION, REQUEST_LOCATION);
            } else {
                proceed();
            }
        } else {
            Utils.T(this, "Please enable your GPS location");
            Intent viewIntent = new Intent(Settings.ACTION_LOCATION_SOURCE_SETTINGS);
            startActivity(viewIntent);
        }
    }


    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        proceed();
    }


    @Override
    public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String[] permissions, @NonNull int[] grantResults) {
        super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);

        switch (requestCode){
            case REQUEST_LOCATION :
                if (Utils.permissionGranted(requestCode, REQUEST_LOCATION, grantResults, 1)){
                    proceed();
                } else {
                    Utils.t(this, "Go to settings and enable permissions");
                }
        }
    }


    public void proceed() {
    new CountDownTimer(3000, 100) {
        public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
            if (Math.round((float)millisUntilFinished / 1000.0f) != countTime) {
                countTime = Math.round((float) millisUntilFinished / 1000.0f);
            }
        }
        public void onFinish() {
            tv_detect.setText("Done!");
            intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MainActivity.class);
            startActivity(intent);
            finish();
        }
    }.start();
}
```

**MainActivity.java**

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements
        OnMapReadyCallback, LocationListener,
        GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks,
        GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener,
        View.OnClickListener, GoogleMap.OnMarkerClickListener {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        buildGoogleApiClient();
    }

    protected synchronized void buildGoogleApiClient() {
    mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
            .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
            .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this)
            .addApi(LocationServices.API)
            .build();
    mGoogleApiClient.connect();
   }


   @Override
   protected void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    // stop location updates when Activity is no longer active
    if (mGoogleApiClient != null) {
        LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.removeLocationUpdates(mGoogleApiClient, this);
       }
   }

  // The rest of method is already implemented
}
```

Error :

> Unable to pause activity
>   {xx.xxx.com.xxx/xx.xxx.com.xxx.ui.activity.MainActivity}:
>   java.lang.IllegalStateException: GoogleApiClient is not connected yet.

Problem : Error happen when I put `proceed()` method on onResume and it will generate twice `MainActivity.java` twice. When I remove the `proceed()` from `onResume` it will works fine, but I need to use `onResume` because when the activity is paused (user go to settings to turn on the GPS) and coming back to the apps it will stuck and do nothing which is not convenient.

Any help is really appreciated. Thanks

Comment: what is configview() ?

Comment: @Enzokie, please refer back to question. Already update the problems.

Comment: @AJay  it was `ui` declaration.

Comment: Try to update your onResume() to this:
@Override
    protected void onResume() {
        proceed();
        super.onResume();
    }

Comment: @HonorLT it still same. Got the same error.

Answer (score 0):

you need to check that mGoogleApiClient is connected in onPause() of MainActivity.java 
so you should do this in onPause()

```
if (mGoogleApiClient != null && mGoogleApiClient.isConnected()) {
    LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.removeLocationUpdates(mGoogleApiClient, this);
   }
}
```

Comment: I need to put this on `MainActivity.java` ? The error was occur at `StartActivity.java`. Need to check (whether user turn on GPS or not) was happen at `StartActivity.java`. After that, it will redirect to `MainActivity.java`.

Comment: yes in MainActivity.java

Comment: `proceed();` was at `StartActivity.java`, could you please read the questions.

Comment: sorry you need to  connect googleApiClient in StartActivity and add isConnected check in StartActivity.java

Comment: still got the error. Are you sure I need to connect googleApiClient at the `StartActivity.java`.

Comment: yes u need to connect at StartActivity.java.. are u getting same error?

Comment: yes, it was error. I dont want to implement GoogleApiClient methods into `StartActivity.java`

Comment: can u show onPause of MainActivity.java

Comment: updated as request.

Comment: How should I implement return back to `StartActivity()` from GPS settings window.

Answer (score 0):

check this condition in onResume(), because when first time create StartActivity.java it call onResume() and when back from setting it call onResume second time.

```
if (Utils.isGPSEnabled(this)) {
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
            requestPermissions(PERMISSIONS_LOCATION, REQUEST_LOCATION);
        } else {
            proceed();
        }
    } else {
        Utils.T(this, "Please enable your GPS location");
        Intent viewIntent = new Intent(Settings.ACTION_LOCATION_SOURCE_SETTINGS);
        startActivity(viewIntent);
    }
```

Comment: It's still error. Plus, the `proceed()` method call twice.